# How calling the raw data reshaping process to form, which we can easily access to desired data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, terminology

Typical situation: some application stores data in external file on database. Ideally, the data structure should has such structure as it's easy to access to any desired value from program. But reality is differ: we need to transform raw data to other structure, that could be easy to access from the code. What the name of this transformation process?

Potentially wrong answer: "mapping". As far as I know, the "mapping" is the definition of conformity between two data sets. In this question, we are considering single data set.

Example: we recieved below data:

```
const rawData = {
    foo: {
        a: 'asdf',
        b: 'nhyt'
    },
    bar: {
        a: 'gfdsa',
        b: 'sdasdf'
    }
}
```

But we want that to iterate by `b` value. So, before that, we need to (*most appropriate synonym of "transform" here*) it to:

```
const preprocessedData = { // optimized? mapped? reduced? reshaped?
    [rawData.foo.b]: {
        name: 'foo',
        a: 'asdf'
    },
    [rawData.bar.b]: {
        name: 'bar',
        a: 'gfdsa'
    }
 }
```

Please note that now **we don't discuss HOW to reshape** data to make it more reachable. I just want to know, how called process when we make data more reachable. It should be something like "mapping" or "optimization", but none of them is right answer, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use for loop, all the function like `map`, `reshape` just for reduce your coding workload and make it more readable, it's not necessary. Beside, if you do it right, performance of for loop is better than function like `map`.

```js
var rawData = {
    foo: {
        a: 'asdf',
        b: 'nhyt'
    },
    bar: {
        a: 'gfdsa',
        b: 'sdasdf'
    }
}

var preprocessedData = {};
for(key in rawData) {
 var obj = rawData[key]; 
 preprocessedData[obj.b] = {name:key, a:obj.a};
}

console.log(preprocessedData);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Here, we don't discuss HOW to reshape data to make it more reachable. I just want to know, how called process when we make data more reachable. It should be something like "mapping" or "optimization", but none of them is right answer, I suppose.

Comment: I don't think there is a name for this simple transforming... Maybe you can use the term `data massage` ?

Comment: "massage"? It's interesting :)